# Best way to centre figure in float

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables)

There are (at least) two ways of centering a single figure / graphic horizontally in a figure float:

1) using `\begin{centering}` in the float

2) using a `\hfill` left and right of the figure

What is the better / more robust / more LaTeX way of doing this?

Comment: The question you refer to does not include the `\hfill` option, so I do not think it is a duplicate

Comment: `\begin{centering}` is wrong. It's `\centering`. The reason why it still compiles is that `\begin{foo}` calls `\foo` and `\end{foo}` calls `\endfoo` if it exists. You might have confused it with `\begin{center}`, but it should not be used in floats because it is intended for normal texts and therefore adds vertical space.

Comment: Nope - I used it on purpose, because this is what I saw somehwere.

Comment: @Rainer: Well, its still wrong ;-) Please add `@username` (without any spaces, i.e. `@MartinScharrer` in my case) to your comments if you answer other comments, so that this user gets notified. The author of the Q or A where the comments are placed under is always notified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended way is

```
\begin{figure}
\centering\includegraphics{whatever}
\caption{A nice figure.}
\end{figure}
```

The `center` environment adds additional unnecessary space around the float.

Comment: So something like '\renewenvironment{figure}[1][]{
 \@float{figure}
 \centering}
 {\end@float}' would be the best if it concerns all floats?

Comment: @IanThompson: no, that makes only sense when you have a `\caption`. without a caption a `center` environment is the better choice.

Comment: @Herbert --- Good point. I never even considered a float without a caption.

Comment: @IanThompson I agree with Herbert: if a figure can't float, then it doesn't need a caption, because it's part of the text it's in. If it needs a caption, then it may be let to float. However this is more likely for tables than figures.

Comment: looks a lot like [@lockstep's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2652/6621)

Answer (score 3):

As explained in [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables) `\centering` is recommended. It's AFAIK the standard way to do it. The `center` environment should not be used because it adds vertical space and is not intended for images. `\hfill` is a low-level TeX macro, not a LaTeX macro. It can be used by experienced users to get special behavior but should only be used if required.

Note that you can also center (or right align) images easily using my `adjustbox` package. It allows you to add a `center` key to `\includegraphics` or even turn an image directly into a figure:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mwe}% For example images only

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{image}
    \caption{Caption (already centered).}
    \label{fig:example1}
\end{figure}
\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth,center]{image}
    \caption{Caption (already centered).}
    \label{fig:example2}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\adjustimage{width=.8\textwidth,center,caption=[Short Caption]{Long Caption},label=fig:example3,figure}{image}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: In addition, the thread also mentions floatrow package - many ways. Thanks for clarifying the \hfill option.